# Device tree for SoC with multiple, differing ARM cores

Tags: arm, embedded, device-tree

So, I've been working on updating the firmware on an older (2011 or so) CCTV/DVR system based on the hi3520v100 chip, and in the process discovered the requirement of a device tree.

The thing is, this SoC has two different cores, one is arm1176 and the other arm926 (not 100% sure on that, as I don't have the code in front of me atm).

So, my question here is how does one handle this situation in device tree? Every multi-core arm dts/i I've looked at has multiple identical cores.

Comment: Quite broad argument. It depends on the `SoC`. For example with `i.MX6SX`, that is an asymmetrical dual core, Only the `A9` core works with linux. The only things to do into dts is to disable on `A9` side resource used by `M4`. `M4` firmware is loaded by u-boot and `M4` core is kikked by `A9`.

Comment: Interesting info. I believe both cores are linux compatible, as the vendor sdk has code for both, and the firmware has two kernels

Comment: Weird. First time I hear about dual kernel. BTW dual kernel means I guess means different memory regions in RAM and different DTBs. Probably those 2 arm haven't got shared resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Describe the CPU that an instance of Linux is running on to whichever CPU that is. This is an AMP system; you cannot run the *same* instance of Linux across both CPUs. Neither of them are SMP capable, and they implement different, incompatible, architecture versions anyway. If both CPUs share the same RAM, then you'll need to partition it up and describe a separate piece to each, although you may want to also declare a shared (uncached) area for communication between the two OSes.

If the system design is such that one CPU is responsible for starting the other after booting itself, then you'll probably want to look into the remoteproc framework for that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm still in the process of figuring out this particular piece of hardware, so its nice to have another thing to google against.